# Do we need to read the input completely in Turing machine?

Tags: turing-machines

This question is motivated from the question [$\mathrm{SPACE}(o(\log\log n)) = \mathrm{SPACE}(O(1))$](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/71795/proving-that-mathrmspaceo-log-log-n-mathrmspaceo1). I am wondering, how is it  possible to decide a language without reading the entire input. I have seen the similar situation in space complexity ( L and NL ,where we define new model of computation).

My model of computation is Turing machine (for e.g. see lecture note on [Turing machine](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4820/2012su/handouts/turingm.pdf))

**My question :**  Do we need to read the input completely in Turing machine ?

Comment: My answer would be a simple "No." if only stackexchange allowed such short answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such requirement. A Turing machine which decides a language can do whatever it wants as long as it always halts; the language it decides is the set of words which it accepts.

There are many languages which don't require reading the entire input:

- The empty language.
- The complete language.
- The language of all words starting with 0.
- The language of words of length 2.

Here is a more non-trivial example:

- Given a language $L$, define the language
  $$ X(L) = \{ 0^\ell 1 w x : |w|=\ell \text{ and } w \in L \}. $$
  The language $X(L)$ can be decided by a Turing machine which doesn't always read the entire input. Moreover, generally speaking $L$ and $X(L)$ have roughly the same complexity (though $X(L)$ requires the ability to count).

Comment: @hopingGI_in_P That is a completely unrelated question, not a comment.

Comment: All languages decidable in constant time are regular.