# Is $\mathsf{DSPACE}(n)=\mathsf{DSPACE}(n/\log\log n)$?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes, space-complexity

We know that $\mathsf{DSPACE}(\log\log n) = \mathsf{DSPACE}(1)$ [according to this proof](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/71795/proving-that-mathrmspaceo-log-log-n-mathrmspaceo1).
Can we claim that $\mathsf{DSPACE}(n)=\mathsf{DSPACE}(n/\log\log n)$ or something like $\mathsf{DSPACE}(n^3)=\mathsf{DSPACE}(n^3/(\log\log n)^k)$ for some $k\in \mathbb{N} $?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [space hierarchy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_hierarchy_theorem) shows that your classes are different.