# $\log n$ lower bound for space complexity

Tags: complexity-theory, space-complexity, lower-bounds

I am currently reading Arora and Barak's *Computational complexity*. In Chapter 4 (Space complexity), they say the following:

> Since the TM's work tapes are separated from its input tape, it makes sense to consider space-bounded machines that use space less than the input length, namely, $S(n) < n$. This is in contrast to time-bounded computation, where $\mathbf{DTIME}(T(n))$ for $T(n) < n$ does not make much sense since the TM does not have enough time to read the entire input. We will require however than $S(n) > \log n$ **since the work tape has length $n$** [my highlight], and we would like the machine to at least be able to "remember" the index of the cell of the input tape that it is currently reading.

I doubt that the highlighted statement is true.
As you can see, it says that to be able to remember the indexes of input tape, so

> “Since the work tape has length $n$”

could not be true and it should be

> “Since the *input tape* has length $n$”

If this is not a typo, I am confused why it mentions that the work tape has length of $n$, as we know that it may have smaller length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Congratulations! You have found a typo in Arora and Barak's long textbook. There are likely many more.

Arora and Barak are not completely correct that the regime $S(n) \leq \log n$ is not interesting. In fact, what we do know is that the regime $S(n) = o(\log\log n)$ is not interesting, since Turing machines using that much space can only accept regular languages, and so can be modified to use no space at all. See for example [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/71795/proving-that-mathrmspaceo-log-log-n-mathrmspaceo1).

The bound $\log\log n$ is tight here, in the sense that there is a non-regular language which can be accepted in space $O(\log \log n)$, namely the language consisting of all words of the form $$ 0\#1\#10\#11\#100\#\cdots\#\mathrm{bin}(m), $$
where $\mathrm{bin}(m)$ is the binary representation of $m$, which has length $O(\log m)$. This language can be accepted in space $O(\log\log m)$ (we only need to index words of length $O(\log m)$), whereas the input length is $\Omega(m)$. This example is taken from [Michel's survey of space complexity](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82734816.pdf), where it is attributed to Wagner and Wechsung, *Computational complexity*.